# How does myFlip f = \ x y -> f y x work?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

In the Haskell book of Allen and Moronuki, at page 240, it is given as the implementation of the *flip* function as that

```
myFlip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
myFlip f = \ x y -> f y x
```

However, I do not understand how does this work ? In particular, when I supply two arguments to *f* as

```
flippedF = flip f
flippedF p q
```

how does Haskell matches *p* and *q* with *x* and *y* in the implementation ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it is a lambda function. it matches the input. Like a `map (\x -> x+1) [1..10]` would match every x in the list.

So if the function is instead of this form `(\x y -> f x y) p q` it matches on two input elements instead.

Comment: You are right. I wasn't seeing that lamda expression as a whole function. I mean if the auhor were to write "flip f = (\ x y -> f y x)", there would be ne problem for me.Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Just try to see the parentheses every time after `=`.

Answer (score 5):

As you have defined `myFlip f = ،،`, you can whenever you see `myFlip f` somewhere replace it with the definition (if the parameter is called something different from `f`, you'll of course need to substitute it).

So, the definition `flippedF = myFlip f` is equivalent to `flippedF = \x y -> f y x`, or as we'd normally write it

```
flippedF x y = f y x
```

(which is really just syntactic sugar for the lambda formulation). If you then evaluate `flippedF p q`, the `x` and `y` parameters are replaced with `p` and `q`, respectively, just like they would in any other function invocation.

```
flippedF p q ≡ (let x = p; y = q in f y x)
             ≡ f q p
```